# applications of linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

I’m writing a paper on the applications of linear differential equations[undergraduate level] could be in physics, chemistry, engineering, business..etc, since I am fairly new to doing research, can someone help me by giving ideas as to what applications would be good to include.
thanks

Comment: maybe this will be helpfull

http://work.colum.edu/~cshaw/old/class_221/lecture_10.4.pdf

Comment: @sara132: http://www.engr.sjsu.edu/trhsu/Chapter%203%20First%20order%20DEs.pdf, http://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~lvrmr/2012-2013-F/Classes/MATH246/NOTES/FirstEqn2.pdf, http://ask.fxplus.ac.uk/tools/HELM/pages/workbooks_1_50_jan2008/Workbook19/19_4_applications_diffrntl_eqns.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The second-order ordinary differential equation
[$$\ddot{x}+2\,p\,\dot{x}+\omega^2x=f(t)$$](https://archive.org/stream/VectorMechanicsForEngineersDynamics/BeerJohnston-VectorMechanicsForEngineersDynamics#page/n499/mode/2up)
describes damped forced vibrations of mass-spring systems, which is quite a topic in mechanics and has an application in automotive engineering, hopefully interesting for your purpose.

---

Another popular ODE, of order $1$ but non-linear, describes a model of population growth and is called [*logistic equation*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html).

Comment: The logistic equation is non linear

Comment: @worldsmithhelper thank you for your peer review!! Edited accordingly, I may elaborate more soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Kepler's laws of planetary motion can be derived from Newton's law of gravitation and newtons laws of motion and solving the differential equations

Comment: Newton's law of gravitation and Kepler's laws of planetary motion are non-linear